# VBA: how to color rows based on value in a spesific column - Coloring wrong sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I need to color rows in Excel sheet 6 based on the value in column F. Everything works fine except the code is coloring the rows in Excel sheet 1! Help?

Here is my code:

```
Sub color()

i = 2

Sheets(6).Select

For Each c In Sheets(6).Range("F2:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    If Cells(i, 6).Value > 50 Then
        Rng = "A" & i & ":" & "H" & i
        Range(Rng).Interior.color = 4 'green

        ElseIf Cells(i, 6).Value < 35 Then
        Rng = "A" & i & ":" & "H" & i
        Range(Rng).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red

        Else
        Rng = "A" & i & ":" & "H" & i
        Range(Rng).Interior.ColorIndex = 2

    End If
    i = i + 1

    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Rng).Interior.color = 4` » `Sheets(6).Range(Rng).Interior.color = 4`

Comment: @DaveRook It's ok, this comment was intentional. (btw. I never got a reminder that one of my answers was automatically converted to a comment. Can I recheck them somehow?)

Answer (score 1):

This macro will color each row according to the value in column "F".

If the row is empty or the value is not a number, it will be skipped.

```
Sub color()

  Dim color As Integer

  For Each cell In Sheets(6).Range("F2:F65536")

    If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
    If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo nextcell:

    If cell.Value > 50 Then
      color = 4
    ElseIf cell.Value < 35 Then color = 3
    Else: color = 2
    End If
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = color
nextcell:
  Next cell

End Sub
```

In your code above you are using two types of loops simultaneously. The `For Each` loop you used loops through each element of the array you provide it. In this case the array is a range of cells.

Each iteration of a `For Each` loop uses the variable name you provide in the declaration as a reference to the element of the array. So in the above instance, each iteration will assign a cell in column F to the variable name I gave `cell`.

All that to say that when you are using a `For Each` loop, you don't need to use an incrementing index variable (like `i`) to call a cell because you already have all the cell object being pointed to with your variable `cell`.